# A class belongTo same class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to design a class that belongTo the same class?

ex. `People1` have an `Account` with a `Balance`, `People2` have the `Account` with that `Balance`

`People1` creates an Event to pass `Credit` from `People1->Account` to `People2->Account`

So the `Event` table would look like:

`id | people1 | account | amount`

The events:

`1 | foo | bar | -300`

`2 | foo2| bar | +300`

The Event 1 is related to the Event 2. How can I specify that using a Laravel relationship?

Can I specify the Event class something like `$this->belongTo('App\Event')?`
But in that case Laravel documentation states that the class it belongs to should have a `hasOne` relation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is this:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
}

public function child()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Event');
}
```

This should work without problems. Cheers!

Comment: Nice solution, but how about the Schema? Should it contains "child_id" and "parent_id" columns too? Because if the relationship link the the same foreign_key, both, hasOne and BelongsTo return an event object, indifferent if the second one is the parent or the child of the first.